# Install a Linux distribution on a USB stick

Tags: linux, live-usb, distribution-choice

I'd like to install a full Linux distribution on my USB stick. I already tried Lili USB Creator, but it did not boot correctly (I had the option "Install" and "Try", but after that I had a black screen). It also had no option for persistent data.

My USB stick is 16 GB. I'd like to partition it for the OS and my personal data.

Are there any possibilities here other than LinuxLive-USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found my solution.

I installed VirtualBox and mounted the ISO with it.
I connected the USB Stick to the VirtualBox and the installation within the Virtual Machine recognized it.
Within the Installation I partitioned the USB Stick with the partioning tool.
It works.

I can now use the USB Stick as a full Linux Distro.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial: [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/). Create a new partition labeled `live-rw` (not `casper-rw`), formatted as `ext2`.

1. Boot from your USB stick. When the boot-menu appear, hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and type `live persistent`.
2. Using UNetbootin you need set the size of the persistent partition:

   [image]
3. Using Lili, OS updates will use up your persistent space, so don’t update often unless you have a lot of available space.

Step 3 sets your persistent partition, e.g. 4000 MB:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I read something about **YUMI**.

[Information about YUMI - CLICK HERE](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

I thought it would be nice to have a UNIX-Distro on USB where to boot from - I think this is the Solution but I didn't give it a try yet.

EDIT: Found out it only can boot to live ...

BUT maybe this [Installation Guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Install-a-Linux-OS-in-your-USB-Flash-Drive-/) gives you some more Details.

Comment: I already tried that Universal USB Installer. It's quite the same like LiLi USB Creator, since it can only boot live.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your distribution has software official for USB live creator: SUSE Linux, Ubuntu, and Fedora have this.

You can download it from official distribution sites. It is optimized for your distribution.

The second way is using other tools: UNetbootin, Linux Live Creator, Yumi, etc.